# Are these numbers $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ writable exploiting other mathematical constants?

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, pi

Let's consider the number
\begin{equation}
\xi_1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n^\textrm{th}\textrm{ digit of $\pi$ in base $2$}}}{n} = 
-1 -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{9}
 + \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{11} + \frac{1}{12} - \frac{1}{13} - \dots 
\end{equation}
where I ignored the dot separation of integer part $11$ with the rest of $\pi$ binary representation. I'm not sure a such number exists: clearly the series is not absolutely convergent, and I don't know how to check convergence of a such "chaotic" (so to speak) sign changing series. I did some numerical explorations to see if they can support the hypothesis that the series converges, exploiting the formula $a_n = \textrm{floor}\left( \pi \cdot {{2}^{n-3}}\right) -2 \textrm{floor}\left( \pi \cdot {{2}^{n-4}}\right)$ found in online encyclopedia of integer sequences: if $n>1$ it gives the sequence of digit of $\pi$ written in base $2$ (leaving away the dot separation of integer part, that is given by the first two digit):
\begin{equation}
1100100100001111110110\dots
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
\xi_1 = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{\textrm{floor}\left( \pi \cdot {{2}^{n-3}}\right) }}{n-1} 
\end{equation}
where I left away the useless unitary denominator $(-1)^{2\cdot\textrm{integer}}$.
Now, if $x\lesssim 50$ the function $f_1(x)=\sum_{n=2}^x \frac{(-1)^{\textrm{floor}\left( \pi \cdot {{2}^{n-3}}\right)}}{n-1}$ doesn't look so regular:

[image]

but if we go on with the sum, things changes: a regular trend is graphically found:

[image]

Unluckily, this trend is very vague is it not sufficient not even to try to guess the limit ($e$? $+\infty$? $\dots$?). My scrap worked more than 3 minutes to plot this, and goes out of memory if with $x>1025$ (we have $f(1025) \approx 2.24806174858$), but surely a more powerful computer can explore deeper this function.

Similarly, what about this series?
\begin{equation}
\xi_2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{{n^{\textrm{th}}\textrm{ digit of $\pi$ in base $2$}}}{n} = 
1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{13} + \frac{1}{14} + \dots 
\end{equation}
Working as done before, we have
$\xi_2 = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{ \textrm{floor}\left( \pi \cdot {{2}^{n-3}}\right) -2 \textrm{floor}\left( \pi \cdot {{2}^{n-4}}\right) }{n-1}$.
This time, the sequence of partial sums is non decreasing. Let's consider the function
\begin{equation}
f_2(x) = \sum_{n=2}^x \frac{ \textrm{floor}\left( \pi \cdot {{2}^{n-3}}\right) -2 \textrm{floor}\left( \pi \cdot {{2}^{n-4}}\right) }{n-1}
\end{equation}
If $x=10$ this gives $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{8} = \frac{73}{40}=1.825$. If $x=20$ it gives $\frac{2469269}{1113840}\approx 2.2168974$. When $x=84$ the value is
\begin{equation}
\frac{433233218232720513501779}{153615744795583006700400} \approx 2.820239675361568
\end{equation}
and for $x > 84$ my computer cannot find the fraction and any change in the approximated value. This *suggests* that the limiting value (never reached: otherwise $\pi$ would be rational) could be a little bigger than 2.82.